How to calculate the orientation of one 3-axis inclinometer related to another
The scenario is quite complex to be described but it can be narrowed down as follow.
I have a small object (my device) that is placed in any orientation on a surface of a giant shpere, let's say with 10+ meters in diameter. For the sake of my question, it's sticked to the sphere, it does not move.
Instead, the sphere slowly (< 1 Hz) oscillates on all its three axis around a mean point, let's say ±15 °. But it's not a periodic oscillation, it's closer to a random movement that with can threat like a low frequency noise. I don't know where and how the device is placed on the sphere surface.
The goal is to detect the orientation of my device related to the reference frame of the sphere. It means that the movements of the sphere don't matter, since the reference frame is the sphere itself.
My first thought is to use two 3-axis accelerometers: one placed on my device and the other on (in) the sphere. Since both are affected by the sphere's movements I can somehow subtract this bias and the resulting difference should be the inclination (orientation) of my device related to the sphere.
What I do not understand is how to do this "subtraction", since the three axis of the inclinometers are not aligned.
Perhaps I need to calculate the resulting vector (in 3D, not in 2D as I'm used to to...) subtract the vectors (how?) and then return back to the single components x, y, z?
UPDATE
From the comment below I understand I didn't explained the problem well.
I'm not interested in the position of the device on the sphere (like longitude/latitude). I just want to know how the device is oriented (in term of, say, yaw/pitch/roll) compared to the sphere reference (that is the orientation of the xyz axis of the shpere's accelerometers).
I tried to make a drawing:

The expected output is the difference in angles between the two references, no matter where is the device.

why are you trying to do this? ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Re, "[my device is] sticked to the sphere, it does not move." and "The goal is to detect the orientation of my device related to the reference frame of the sphere." That doesn't make sense. If the device is "sticked to the sphere," then its orientation in the reference frame of the sphere never changes. That's what "sticked to the sphere" means. If your goal makes sense to you, then that probably means you need to think of a better way to describe it.

@SolomonSlow I didn't say it changes (since it's "sticked"). I said I need to know its orientation, since it's not known in advance, compared to the sphere reference.

@jsotola Why? Because they asked me to do it... What problem? Detect the orientation of the device placed on the sphere, without knowing in advance where it's positioned. Of course I cannot just "see" it, I need to retrieve it using sensor for further processing.

If I forgot any detail please tell me how to improve the question. Basically I just asked how to subtract the measurements of two 3-axis accelerometers in order to detect the difference in orientation between the twos.

if the sphere is stationary, then you can only detect the latitude, not the longitude

@jsotola sorry, I understand my English is not so good. I didn't asked for latitude/latitude (that would be the absolute position of the device on the sphere). I'm looking just for its orientation, say pitch/roll/yaw of the device.

I'm saying that the sensor will have the same reading anywhere along a line of latitude when the sphere is stationary ... if you know the sphere motion, then you can also deduce the longitude from the changes that the sensor detects

the update indicates that the sphere is irrelevant to what you are trying to do

@jsotola well, since I don't know how it works, I tried to add all the details I thought relevant. I didn't know the sphere was not relevant, sorry. Better an unuseful detail more than one less. It would be very kind of you if you might elaborate an answer then.

I do not know an answer ... I understand the problem ... you are trying to calculate the orientation of a sensor relative to another sensor ... the two sensors are mechanically linked, and the whole assembly rotates randomly in 3D
